# Highlight line graph with dotted lines

Tags: javascript, graph, charts

[image]I want a line graph like the image below using some opensource js library. I am using Charts.js currently but apparently it doesn't have something like this.

I want a section of the graph to be highlighted using dotted lines.

Which opensource lib can I use ?How can I do this ?

Comment: Use Highcharts, instead.

Answer (score 0):

If border: 1px black dotted is not working, try outline: 1px black dotted;

Comment: I want it only for a  section of the graph..not the entire graph

Comment: Can you give me a fiddle, code example or active page to look at? You should be able to select it somehow.

Comment: Hey tony..that isn't working..sorry ..please see the edited question !